# How to get list of translatable messages

Tags: command-line, gettext

I know how to translate a natural language message into the user's language using gettext.

But now I am wondering how to obtain a list of all translatable messages in a given domain.

I have obtained a raw result with something like this:

```
strings /usr/share/locale/${LANG:0:2}/LC_MESSAGES/$DOMAIN.mo
```

but I am looking for a neater solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [`xgettext`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html) program extracts translatable strings from `.po` files, which are the [source files](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgfmt-Invocation.html) for the `.mo` files found in `/usr/share/locale`. These `.po` files should be included in the source distribution of the package for which you want to translate messages.

If you need to work with `.mo` files, you can translate them back to `.po` with [`msgunfmt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/msgunfmt-Invocation.html).

Comment: +1 for the useful info, but requiring the source package is not the solution i'm looking for